# How can I replace the short(screw connecting) wire for a middle-of-run outlet replacement?

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair

I’m referring to the very short wires the come from the wire groups pigtail directly to the terminal screw. The wires that was in the old outlet before were decades old and torn. I thought since they were not being fed through the wall like the others, it won’t be an issue to get more wire. But I don’t know wether I should pull more wire through or cut a price off any existing wire since I’m unfamiliar with this wiring over

Here[image: this is the receptacle]

Comment: It is unclear what you mean, can you give a little more detail and perhaps a photo?

Comment: @Alaskaman yes I take a photo of it now. Sorry I’m brand new to this site. How to upload phone in a comment? Or do have to make it a separate post?

Comment: Below your question text is keywords.  Below the keywords is some text "share [edit] delete flag" etc.   You hit [edit] and you are back to the compose window and can make changes.  Along the top is an add picture button.

Comment: Ok. Just uploaded it. Thank you. Let know what you think

Comment: The photo helps, i am still not sure what you are trying to accomplish, all the wire appear to be about the same length. Are you just replacing an outlet? Did you take note of how the old one was wired up? *It appears the the two of each color were connected with wire nuts and the other two went to the terminals on the outlet*. **What is your question?**

Comment: Figured it out! I just a price of one the neutral and hot wires to make a 4th wire to the pigtails. Made the tips even, capped them and made sure the wires were all still in place. Turned the breaker on and solved that issue. But no 2/3 outlets and 1/2 light witch in original bedroom, still do not work. So at least I narrowed it down to know it’s not a circuit in the breaker, it’s a wiring issue or a jumper somewhere..

Comment: What I think is being asked, and might be the answer, you need to make a pigtail for each color, and nut them together. White to white(all) and black to black(all). Then your pigtail's will attach to the new outlet. I think your other room issue is that they share the circuit and you have removed the hot from the circuit to the other room, and the neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before, on each side, you had 1 wire going directly to a screw, and 2 wires joining a short pigtail under a wirenut, then the pigtail going to the other screw.  That's a silly way to  do it.

Rearrange the parts you already have so that all the white wires and the pigtail are joined on one wire nut. Then run only the pigtail to the new receptacle.  So only 1 wire will be on each side of the receptacle.  That is a much better way to do that thing.  This will work best with red or tan wire nuts.

What's happening here is that one of the cables (b/w/red?/bare) is coming from the supply / breaker panel, and the other two cables are branching in two different directions to go onward to other loads.  All 3 cables need to have their wires joined and the power must also go to a fourth place, the receptacle proper.  That's why 4 wires are involved.

It's real common for less experienced folks to get tripped up in wiring methods like this.  Who really cares if you use 4 screws or only 2 on the receptacle?  Not I, and not electrons.  The important thing is all the blacks get connected together and all the whites.  (Mind you, that's not the rule everywhere, but it's the rule in this junction box today.)

You cannot pull more wire out of the wall.  Do not waste what you got.